# How to use node-fetch

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I used this code snippet, but I keep getting errors in the terminal, what could be the reason?

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

npm install node-fetch

Comment: what is error ??

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you currently have and the error you're getting for it

Comment: "*I keep getting errors in the terminal*" *What* errors? Why haven't you included them here? Can you link to a specific document that shows this syntax should be valid? [ask]

Comment: Note https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module

Answer (score 1):

node-fetch is an ESM-only module from v3.0.0 - you are not able to import it with require

Try importing node-fetch instead:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

It's likely that you have installed node-fetch 3.0.0.
In order to test if this is the case, please uninstall the module

```
npm uninstall node-fetch
```

Then attempt to install node-fetch v2.6.1

```
npm install node-fetch@2.6.1
```

You should be able to import using require now.

Comment: I get an error saying I cannot use 'import' outside of node_modules

Comment: I get this error in the terminal                                                                           C:\Users\User\Documents\My projects\greenlifeapp\controllers\auth.controller.js:6
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I have updated my original answer, please give that a go

Comment: It works now, though with require rather than an import. Thanks anyways